# Creating Json data from three lists using Python

Tags: python, json

I have two lists:

```
Name = [ "John Doe" , "Jane Roe"]
Age = [25, 24]
```

I need to have the data in the following json format using Python 3:

```
[ { "Name": "John Doe", "Age" : 25 } 
{   "Name": "Jane Roe", "Age" : 26 } ]
```

Kindly suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: Did you try the most obvious `[{'Name' : x, 'Age': y} for x, y in zip(Name, Age)]`?

Comment: Thanks .. I just blanked out .

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
import json
Name = [ "John Doe" , "Jane Roe"]
Age = [25, 24]
new_age = json.dumps([{'Name':a, 'Age':b} for a, b in zip(Name, Age)])
```